# bounded linear function on Hibert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Let $\nu,\mu$ be finite measure defined on the same $\sigma-$algebra and $\nu<<\mu$(that is $\nu$ is absolutly continuous w.r.t $\mu$)

Prove linear functional $\ell:L^2(\nu+\mu) \to \mathbb{C}$ which is defined as $\ell(x) = \int x d\mu$ is bounded with respect to $L^2(\mu+\nu)$(That is $|\ell(x)|\le C \|x\|_{2,(\mu+\nu)}$)

I know how to prove bounded w.r.t $L^2(\mu)$ by Holder inequality what about $L^2(\mu+\nu)$

My attempt we have shown $d\nu = gd\mu$ for some $g\ge 0 $  a.e.

Then $(1+g) \ge 1$ a.e. so if we represent $\|x\|^2_{2.(\nu+\mu)}= \int((1+g)x^2)d\mu$ the result is obvious,is my proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, by the Lebesgue-Radon-Nikodym theorem we have that $d\nu=gd\mu$ where $g\geq0$ a.e. is an integrable function (since $\nu$ is finite). So, if $f\in L^2(\mu+\nu)$ we have that

$$|\ell(f)|=|\int_X fd\mu|\leq\int_X|f|d\mu\leq\int_X|f|(1+g)d\mu=\int_X|f|d(\mu+\nu)=\int_X1\cdot|f|d(\mu+\nu)\leq\bigg(\int_X1^2d(\mu+\nu)\bigg)^{1/2}\cdot\bigg(\int_X|f|^2d(\mu+\nu)\bigg)^{1/2}=(\mu+\nu)(X)^{1/2}\cdot\|f\|_{L^2(\mu+\nu)}.$$

So your functional is bounded and its norm is at most $(\mu+\nu)(X)^{1/2}$ (yes your proof is correct, I just wrote down the dets).